# Qt Creator LNK1104: cannot open file 'glu32.lib'

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++

I have been learning C++ for about a year now, not a complete noobie, but recently decided to learn how to create GUIs, so after a little research I figured Qt was the tool for me.

Grabbed Qt and wanted to get into the Qt Creator following thenewboston's Youtube tutorials, but any (even empty) project I attempt to run gets an error

```
LNK1104: cannot open file 'glu32.lib'.
```

I've been scouring the internet for a solution to this problem for a while - the question has been posed a few times, but solutions either don't apply to me or I can't make head or tail of them (I'm still somewhat of a noobie in many respects).

I could really use some advice on this.

Edit: @hyde Here's the compiler output:

> 17:58:09: Running steps for project untitled...
>
> 17:58:09: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
>
> 17:58:09: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe"
> C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
> echo 1 /* CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID */ 24 /* RT_MANIFEST */   "debug\untitled.exe.embed.manifest">debug\untitled.exe_manifest.rc
>
> if not exist debug\untitled.exe if exist debug\untitled.exe.embed.manifest del debug\untitled.exe.embed.manifest
>
> if exist debug\untitled.exe.embed.manifest copy /Y debug\untitled.exe.embed.manifest debug\untitled.exe_manifest.bak
>
> link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:debug\untitled.exe.embed.manifest /OUT:debug\untitled.exe @C:\Users\Immi\AppData\Local\Temp\untitled.exe.3464.31.jom
>
> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'glu32.lib'
>
> jom: C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\build-untitled-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MSVC2012_OpenGL_32bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\untitled.exe] Error 1104
>
> jom: C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\build-untitled-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MSVC2012_OpenGL_32bit-Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2
>
> 17:58:10: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
>
> Error while building/deploying project untitled (kit: Desktop Qt 5.3 MSVC2012 OpenGL 32bit)
>
> When executing step "Make"
>
> 17:58:10: Elapsed time: 00:01.

Comment: Please add the console output of the clean build of your "empty" project (by which I assume, just empty `main` function or something) to the question. Also tell what Qt Creator Kit you are using (for example, "Desktop Qt 5.2.1 MSVC2010 32bit OpenGL" is one I have).

Comment: Also, try `dir /s C:\glu32.lib` and see where you have that file, if anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, I mis-phrased that - it doesn't even compile, so there is no build and no console output. I'm using Qt 5.3.2 MSVC2010 32bit OpenGL.  
I do appear to have the file numerous times, either in subdirectories of C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\ or C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped! I meant, add *compile* output (which you do have if you got linker error).

Comment: @hyde Ok, added it. Also correction - the kit I'm using is Desktop Qt 5.3 MSVC2012 32bit OpenGL. Sorry about that, looked in the wrong place before.

Comment: I added tag for MSVC, hopefully someone more familiar with it can help you solve this. But the core of the problem is, either linker is somehow missing the path for that *.lib*, or the lib it finds in its paths is somehow not the right one (could possibly be 32/64 bit issue, maybe).

Comment: Anyway, one solution is to install the MinGW version (easy with online installer, if you have decent internet connection), it's what I usually use on Windows. Or just try re-installing what you have now, in case the installation was somehow botched up. Also, make sure you have up-to-date display drivers from your GPU maker (that shouldn't matter with build time problems, though, just saying).

Comment: Ok, I installed MinGW, then re-installed Qt Creator because I couldn't figure out how to add the kit otherwise and it finally compiles. Thanks a lot - it may not be quite the solution I was looking for but it'll suit me :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it like this:

- In **Qt Creator** I selected **Projects**.
- In **Build & Run** – **Build Enviroment** I clicked **Details**.
- I started to edit the **LIB variable** and added the
  following to the string C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
  SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib\ (you need to have some Windows SDK
  installed).

Now then I rebuild my project it compiled and I was able to run. But debugging wasn’t working. I solved that by reading on this page http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-debugger-engines.html where I found (after some guessing) that I needed to install **Get the standalone debugging tools (WinDbg) as part of Windows 8.1 SDK** from this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365

**Personal note:** I you are new to GUI development I would recommend that you start to look on something else. I’m not saying QT is bad in any way, but it feels like the environment could you cause a lot of problem which may take your motivation away (to be fair: I’m a QT newbie). I would start with C# (very easy if you know C++) and create some programs with Visual Studio – it’s very easy to learn and you will be productive and creative and having fun which is important when you want to learn something.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the .pro file contains the following:

```
QT       += core gui opengl
LIBS     += opengl32.lib -lglu32
```